# How to map the value from xml input to the value outside of xml with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have integration from Greenhouse recruiting system to workday HR System. candidates will be hired into workday from greenhouse system, basically green house system will be generating
position and manager name, and based on manager name XSLT should look for the organization that manager is managing in workday and place position under that organization. Can we map Manager field from Greenhouse with their organization in workday and have position under that Organization.

Following sample xml input from greenhouse

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <root>
               <data>
               <action>hire_candidate</action>
                <payload>
                <application>
                 <id>284166</id>
                  <opening>
                <opening_id>P11223</opening_id>
              </opening>
               <candidate>  
             <id>256</id>
             <first_name>Daniel</first_name>
             <last_name>Mathew</last_name>
             <title>IT Analyst</title>
             </candidate>
             <offer>
            <id>4269688005</id>
            <version>1</version>
            <starts_at>2023-08-20</starts_at>
            <custom_fields>
              <reporting_manager_offer_1687533918.5161974>
                 <name>Reporting Manager</name>
                 <type>user</type>
                 <value>
                    <user_id>4226646005</user_id>
                    <name>David Gale</name>
                    <employee_id>100122</employee_id>
                 </value>
                </reporting_manager_offer_1687533918.5161974>
               </custom_fields>
               </offer>
              </application>
             </payload>
            </data>
            </root>
```

Following sample XSLT to transform XML data, and this XSLT will be creating position in workday

````
            ``` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="supervisory_org"/>
<xsl:param name="cost_center"/>
<xsl:param name="job_title"/>
<xsl:param name="company_code"/>
<xsl:param name="region"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <env:Envelope
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <env:Body>
    <wd:Create_Position_Request xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" wd:version="v29.0">
        <wd:Business_Process_Parameters>
            <wd:Auto_Complete>true</wd:Auto_Complete>
            <wd:Run_Now>true</wd:Run_Now>
        </wd:Business_Process_Parameters>
        <wd:Create_Position_Data>
     <!-- HERE THIS ORGANIZATION SHOULD BE PULLED OR MAPPED FROM WORKDAY BASED ON THE MANAGER   
      NAME FROM GREENHOUSE XML INPUT-->
            <wd:Supervisory_Organization_Reference>
             <xsl:value-of select="$supervisory_org"/>
            </wd:Supervisory_Organization_Reference>
            <wd:Position_Data>
                <wd:Job_Posting_Title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$job_title"/>
                </wd:Job_Posting_Title>
            </wd:Position_Data>
          </wd:Create_Position_Data>
       </wd:Create_Position_Request>
      </env:Body>
     </env:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>

    Expected Output (Sample)

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <row>
<candidate_Data>
    <first_name>Daniel</first_name>
    <last_name>Mathew</last_name>
</candidate_Data>
<position_data>
    <position_id>P11223</position_id>
    <job_title>IT Analyst</job_title>
    <supervisory_org>SO22</supervisory_org><!-- SO22 IS THE ORGANIZATION ID DAVID GALE
       IS MANAGING IN WORKDAY-->
   </position_data> 
       </row>
````

i did try hardcoding organization name as below, but since i have around 200 managers, this is not working as expected.

```
         <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when
         test="offer/custom_fields/reporting_manager_offer_1687533918.5161974/name='Daniel  
         Mathew'">
                           <xsl:text>SO22</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when
      test="offer/custom_fields/reporting_manager_offer_1687533918.5161974/name='John Smith'">
                            <xsl:text>SO23</xsl:text>
      <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>SO11</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
```

I would like to see if there is anyway to map manager value from greenhouse to organization value which is managed by the that manager in workday.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking. Your expected output contains `<supervisory_org>SO22</supervisory_org`. I don't see the value of `SO22` anywhere in your input.

Comment: P.S. Please pick one version of XSLT, not all 3.

Comment: In Input i will not have SO22, i will have manager in the input and based on this , i should be pulling manager's Organization from workday. In this example i have provided, i will have manager name in the input, my query is from manager value in the input can we pull managers Organization in workday which is SO22.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "pulling [...] from workday". XSLT can process information either from your input XML or from external sources (see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#fns-on-docs). In addition, you can pass data to the stylesheet in parameters. If your question is about that, you need to show us the external source's data. Otherwise it's not about XSLT - perhaps you need to re-tag it.

Comment: As @michael.hor257k says, it all depends on how you get data from Workday. Is this via a REST API for example, in which case you might be able to get data using a call on `document()` with an appropriate URI? If you don't know how to get data from Workday then this is a Workday question not an XSLT question.

Comment: Thanks Michael and michael.hor, i am basically building integration that integrates data from one system to other, from source i have a value that needs to look for a value from target system. From your comments, i am understanding that there is no way that we can call a value when it is not in the xml input or through xpath from external sources. Thank you so much for your valuable time for looking into this.

Comment: You can call any resource by its URI.